# sonata_type_collection show entities in different tabs

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to organize the way Sonata Admin shows sonata_type_collection.
It looks like this now:
[image]
In the source html code I see that all of that is meant to be tabs

```
<div class="sonata-ba-tabs">
    <div>
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#s5860de8a43681_1_1" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="icon-exclamation-sign has-errors hide"></i> -
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="s5860de8a43681_1_1">
                    <fieldset>
                       <!--some field here-->
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#s5860de8a43681_2_1" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="icon-exclamation-sign has-errors hide"></i> -
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="s5860de8a43681_2_1">
                   <fieldset>
                       <!--some field here-->
                   </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I omitted some code to make it shorter)
We can definitely see that it is meant to be some kind of jquery tabs, but I can't really find any information how to make that work like a tabs. Is there anyway to configure the form to implement that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.Is showing each record of the collection in a separate tab what you want to achieve?For the form or show view ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry for the misleading question. I want it for the form in the admin panel.

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer right now but anyways, you will most likely need to copy the html structure of an existing tab and use it to inject new tabs in the dom each time you click the add button for your collection with a javascript event listener if you see what i mean